# Place input box at the center of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div, and I want the input box to be place at it's center. How can I do this?

Comment: can u sow us what you tried and not working?

Comment: Shouldn't this go over to doctype? (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/ ; http://doctype.com/) ... why don't we have a belongs-on-doctype close option?

Answer (score 80):

The catch is that input elements are inline.
   We have to make it block (display:block) before positioning it to center : margin : 0 auto. Please see the code below :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.wrapper {
            width: 300px;
            height:300px;
            border:1px solid black;
        }

        input[type="text"] {
             display: block;
             margin : 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class='wrapper'>
        <input type='text' name='ok' value='ok'>
    </div>    


</body>
</html>
```

But if you have  a div which is positioned = absolute then we need to do the things little bit differently.Now see this!

```
  <html>
     <head>
    <style>
        div.wrapper {
            position:  absolute;
            top : 200px;
            left: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            height:300px;
            border:1px solid black;
        }

        input[type="text"] {
             position: relative;
             display: block;
             margin : 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class='wrapper'>
        <input type='text' name='ok' value='ok'>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Hoping this can be helpful.Thank you.

Comment: "The catch is that input elements are inline" - this is the key! thansk

Comment: why does "margin: 0 auto" center the input?

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct answer. This question is old enough that there should be an override for selecting answers.

Answer (score 37):

You can just use either of the following approaches:

```css
.center-block {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="center-block">
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

```
#the_div input {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I'm not sure if this works in good ol' IE6, so you might have to do this instead.

```
/* IE 6 (probably) */
#the_div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#input_box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#div {
    text-align: center;
}

<div id="div">
    <label for="input_box">Input: </label><input type="text" id="input_box" name="input_box" />
</div>
```

or you could do it using padding, but this is not that great of an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather unconventional way of doing it:

```
#inputcontainer
{
    display:table-cell; //display like a <td> to make the vertical-align work
    text-align:center; //centre the input horizontally
    vertical-align:middle; //centre the input vertically


    width:200px; //widen the div for demo purposes
    height:200px; //make the div taller for demo purposes
    background:green; //change the background of the div for demo purposes
}
```

It might not be the best way to do it, and margin​ won't work, but it does the job. If you need to use margin, then you could wrap the div that displays as a table cell in another 'normal' div.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qw4QW/