# how to center a bootstrap textbox

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

How to center the input text box of bootstrap?

```
 <form action="#" method="post" class="akame-contact-form border-0 p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Your Name" required style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bootstrap asp.net textbox does not center properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074033/bootstrap-asp-net-textbox-does-not-center-properly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place input box at the center of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281403/place-input-box-at-the-center-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so. But the easiest is to use `.text-center`. It sets `text-align` property of input to `center`.

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Read this for more info. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment
[Text-align class for inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829608/text-align-class-for-inside-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

I have used bootstrap 4-

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="akame-contact-form border-0 p-0">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Your Name" required style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```